# How do I upload a txt flatpage into a django based website

Tags: django

What I want to do is, I have a file called abc.txt. I want to upload this into to my website so that it shows on the browser as mysite.com/.well-known/pki-validation/abc.txt. The file (page) contains some text.
I want to do this from terminal by creating a flatpage. I have created views.py and url.

Daniel

Comment: Hello and welcome to community. Your question reveals you are at zero point. Maybe you should start from tutorials how to make an file upload page with django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.